# Find all text until next regex match

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to compile all text until the next match with regex in python. The data is a debate transcript available online.

Presently I am attempting to loop through all matches of the p tag and identify the ones with a labelled speaker and then append all successive text without a labelled speaker to the previous match.

I am not sure if this is the best way to proceed or it would be easier to simply search and group all of the text at once. Presently I have only been able to see all of the text that begins with at least three capitalized letters.

```
import re    
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = rq.get('http://www.cbsnews.com/news/transcript-of-the-2015-gop-debate-9-pm/')
b = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
debatetext = b.find('div', attrs= {'class' , 'entry'}).findAll('p')
pattern = re.compile(r'[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z].*:')
for line in debatetext:
        if re.search(pattern, line.text) is not None:
                print line
```

Example text

```
<p> BUSH:  Here's what I believe.  I believe we're at the verge of the greatest time to be alive in this world.  </p>
<p>   But Washington is holding us back.  How we tax, how we regulate. We're not embracing the energy revolution in our midst, a broken immigration system that has been politicized rather than turning it into an economic driver.  </p>
<p>   We're not protecting and preserving our entitlement system or reforming for the next generation.  All these things languish while we have politicians in Washington using these as wedge issues.  </p>
<p>   Here's my commitment to you, because I did it as Florida.  We can fix these things.  We can grow economically and restore America's leadership in the world, so that everybody has a chance to rise up.  I humbly ask for your vote, whenever you're gonna get to vote, whenever the primary is.  Thank you all very much.  </p>
```

Ideally I would like to append the three lines without "BUSH:" to the first statement or add "BUSH:" or whatever other candidate spoke to the beginning of the line.

EDIT: Larger sample

```
    <div class="entry" itemprop="articleBody" id="article-entry">...


<p>   CARSON:  -- extremely effectively.</p>
<p>   (APPLAUSE)</p>
<p>   BAIER:  Gentlemen, the next series of questions deals with ObamaCare and the role of the federal government.</p>
<p>   Mr. Trump, ObamaCare is one of the things you call a disaster.</p>
<p>   TRUMP:  A complete disaster, yes.</p>
<p>   BAIER:  Saying it needs to be repealed and replaced.</p>
<p>   TRUMP:  Correct.</p>
<p>   BAIER:  Now, 15 years ago, uncalled yourself a liberal on health care.  You were for a single-payer system, a Canadian-style system.</p>
<p>   Why were you for that then and why aren't you for it now?  TRUMP:  First of all, I'd like to just go back to one.  In July of 2004, I came out strongly against the war with Iraq, because it was going to destabilize the Middle East.  And I'm the only one on this stage that knew that and had the vision to say it.  And that's exactly what happened.</p>
<p>   BAIER:  But on ObamaCare...</p>
<p>   TRUMP:  And the Middle East became totally destabilized.  So I just want to say.</p>
<p>   As far as single payer, it works in Canada.  It works incredibly well in Scotland.  It could have worked in a different age, which is the age you're talking about here.</p>
<p>   What I'd like to see is a private system without the artificial lines around every state.  I have a big company with thousands and thousands of employees.  And if I'm negotiating in New York or in New Jersey or in California, I have like one bidder.  Nobody can bid.</p>
<p>   You know why?</p>
<p>   Because the insurance companies are making a fortune because they have control of the politicians, of course, with the exception of the politicians on this stage.</p>
<p>   But they have total control of the politicians.  They're making a fortune.</p>
<p>   Get rid of the artificial lines and you will have...</p>
<p>   (BUZZER NOISE)</p>
<p>   TRUMP:  -- yourself great plans.  And then we have to take care of the people that can't take care of themselves.  And I will do that through a different system.</p>
<p>   (CROSSTALK)</p>
<p>   BAIER:  Mr. Trump, hold up one second.</p>
<p>   PAUL:  I've got a news flash...</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I reformatted my regex slightly, so that it looks like this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'([A-Z]+):(.*)')
```

The + gives me one or unlimited letters that are capitals, so that is just a bit of clean up from the previous regex code. 
I also changed it to create capture groups, the first one being any caps letters before a ':', and the second any text after the ':'.

Now the second match (group(0) is the entire match, group(1) is name) can be used to be appended to a dictionary, and successive text can be appended.

To handle the issues regarding adding the missing statements that follow this initial regex pattern I used a state machine. 
Note this only works because I am assuming that all following text from the regex match should belong the speaker found from the regex pattern.

```
d = {}
name = ''
blurb = ''
state = 0
for line in debatetext:
        m = re.search(pattern, line.text)
        if m:
            name = m.group(1) 
            blurb = m.group(2)
            #skip past speakers section with all caps at beginning
            if name != 'SPEAKERS':
                state = 1                
                if name in d:
                    d[name].append(blurb)
                else:
                    d[name] = [ blurb ]
        else:
            if state:
                d[name].append(line.text)
```

Took a bit of IRL help this time, but I think this solution works well in this instance and could be of help to other people. I've used this to parse the second debate and it worked pretty well. I might tinker with it so that statements are added in order so I can do some correlation analysis in conjunction with twitter data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes to "I am not sure if this is the best way to proceed or it would be easier to simply search and group all of the text at once."  Or, the "best" way is the way that you understand and solves the problem.  This is quick and dirty but should get you started.

```
import pprint

test_data="""    <div class="entry" itemprop="articleBody" id="article-entry">...


<p>   CARSON:  -- extremely effectively.</p>
<p>   (APPLAUSE)</p>
<p>   BAIER:  Gentlemen, the next series of questions deals with ObamaCare and the role of the federal government.</p>
<p>   Mr. Trump, ObamaCare is one of the things you call a disaster.</p>
<p>   TRUMP:  A complete disaster, yes.</p>
<p>   BAIER:  Saying it needs to be repealed and replaced.</p>
<p>   TRUMP:  Correct.</p>
<p>   BAIER:  Now, 15 years ago, uncalled yourself a liberal on health care.  You were for a single-payer system, a Canadian-style system.</p>
<p>   Why were you for that then and why aren't you for it now?  TRUMP:  First of all, I'd like to just go back to one.  In July of 2004, I came out strongly against the war with Iraq, because it was going to destabilize the Middle East.  And I'm the only one on this stage that knew that and had the vision to say it.  And that's exactly what happened.</p>
<p>   BAIER:  But on ObamaCare...</p>
<p>   TRUMP:  And the Middle East became totally destabilized.  So I just want to say.</p>
<p>   As far as single payer, it works in Canada.  It works incredibly well in Scotland.  It could have worked in a different age, which is the age you're talking about here.</p>
<p>   What I'd like to see is a private system without the artificial lines around every state.  I have a big company with thousands and thousands of employees.  And if I'm negotiating in New York or in New Jersey or in California, I have like one bidder.  Nobody can bid.</p>
<p>   You know why?</p>
<p>   Because the insurance companies are making a fortune because they have control of the politicians, of course, with the exception of the politicians on this stage.</p>
<p>   But they have total control of the politicians.  They're making a fortune.</p>
<p>   Get rid of the artificial lines and you will have...</p>
<p>   (BUZZER NOISE)</p>
<p>   TRUMP:  -- yourself great plans.  And then we have to take care of the people that can't take care of themselves.  And I will do that through a different system.</p>
<p>   (CROSSTALK)</p>
<p>   BAIER:  Mr. Trump, hold up one second.</p>
<p>   PAUL:  I've got a news flash...</p>"""

## look for 3 capital letters
## assume every line starts with "<p>" (so won't test for it)

one_group=[]
for record in test_data.split("\n"):
    record=record.strip()
    if len(record):
        split_rec=record.split()
        found=True
        for ltr in split_rec[1][:3]:
            if ltr < "A" or ltr > "Z":
                found=False

        ## found new name so print previous block
        if found and len(one_group):
            pprint.pprint(one_group)
            print
            one_group=[]
        one_group.append(record)

## last group
print one_group
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Curly Joe, I went ahead with my regex method and with a state machine and it worked pretty well